# Is it possible to define a variable in a Swift if statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement

Is it possible to define a variable in a Swift if statement and then use it outside of the statement?

```
    var cellWidth = requiredWidth
    if notification.type == "vote"{
        var cellWidth = maxWidth - 80
        println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
        println("maxWidth is \(maxWidth)")
    }
    println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
```

I could just duplicate the code that uses cellWidth into the if statement, but that seems inefficient. Is there a better approach to handling conditional variables in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can not. The `if` statement defines a local scope, so whatever variable you define inside its scope, won't be accessible outside of it.

You have a few options

```
var cellWidth = requiredWidth
if notification.type == "vote"{
    cellWidth = maxWidth - 80
    println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
    println("maxWidth is \(maxWidth)")
}
println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
```

or (better IMHO) without using variable, but only constants

```
func widthForCell(_ maxWidth: CGFloat, _ requiredWidth: CGFloat, _ notification: Notification) -> CGFloat {
  switch notification.type {
    case "vote": return maxWidth - 80
    default: return requiredWidth
  }
}
let cellWidth = widthForCell(maxWidth, requiredWidth, notification)
println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
```

Comment: Thanks! I much prefer the idea of only using constants.

Comment: I think even better is to not name the function and just do it inside the let cellWidth

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are actually creating two separate variables, both called `cellWidth`. They have different scopes: inside the `if` statement, the `cellWidth` created in that scope is prioritised, as it has the deepest scope; outside the `if` statement, the inner `cellWidth` is not visible, as it cannot access that scope. So with the code above, you will find that the last `println` statement will always print a value equal to `requiredWidth`, even when the if statement is evaluated.

What you actually want to do is just use modify the existing `cellWidth` variable inside the `if` statement:

```
var cellWidth = requiredWidth
if notification.type == "vote"{
    cellWidth = maxWidth - 80
    println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
    println("maxWidth is \(maxWidth)")
}
println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
```

Of course, if your code is actually as simple as shown in the question above, you can simply use:

```
let cellWidth = notificationType == "vote" ? maxWidth - 80 : requiredWidth
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
var cellWidth = maxWidth - 80
```

just use:

```
cellWidth = maxWidth - 80
```

`cellWidth` is already defined outside the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can define it before:

```
var cellWidth = requiredWidth
if notification.type == "vote"{
    cellWidth = maxWidth - 80
    println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
    println("maxWidth is \(maxWidth)")
}
println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)")
```

You can make it an optional value if you don't know before the if statement what the value will be.

Answer (score 1):

You can not define variables inside and `if` statement and then use them outside of the `if`. The `if` body defines a scope and everything that is defined in that scope goes *out of scope* (meaning it is not accessible anymore) when the `if` statements ends.

If you want to change variables inside an `if` and then use them afterwards, they need to be declared in the surrounding scope.

```
var cellWidth = 100
if notification.type == "vote"{
    cellWidth -= 80
    var otherCellWidth = 50
}
println("cellWidth is \(cellWidth)") // cellWidth is 20
println("cellWidth is \(otherCellWidth)") // not possible because otherCellWidth is out of scope
```