# Using a variable outside of a do loop in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102220/is-it-possible-to-define-a-variable-in-a-swift-if-statement), I would like to assign a string to a variable in my `ViewDidLoad`, as I will use this array to populate a table.

```
let downloads : String?

// Get the document directory url
let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

do {
    // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    print(directoryContents)

    // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
    let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
    //print("mp3 urls:",mp3Files)
    let mp3FileNames = mp3Files.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
    //print("mp3 list:", mp3FileNames)

    let downloads = mp3FileNames

} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

First, if I print mp3FileNames without the variable, it prints. So the mp3 download extracting code seems good.

Second, when I add the variable for `downloads`, things break down. XCode flags that I am not using the variable elsewhere even though it reappears in my do loop: `Immutable value 'cars' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it`

I am new to Swift. What is the proper way to set this variable with the string that will come from `mp3FileNames`?

Comment: var downloads : String?

Comment: downloads = mp3FileNames.  (remove let)

Comment: Did u try like this ?

Comment: @McDonal_11: Doesn't look like it's working. On your line, the error: `Variable 'downloads' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it`

Comment: Thats not as error. Its Warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is a rule:

A variable is only visible in the scope where it has been declared (scope are the pair of braces) and its subscopes.

The local variable

```
let downloads = mp3FileNames
```

is declared in the `do` block so it is not the same object as the variable with the same name on the top level. A local declared variable hides a variable with the same name on a higher level.

There are two other major issues.

- The variable on the higher level is declared as optional constant. You can't change it!
- The variable on the higher level is declared as `String` while `mp3FileNames` is an **array** of strings.

If both `downloads` were the same object you would get compiler errors about those issues.

---

Solution:

Declare the variable on the higher level as empty array of string

```
var downloads = [String]()
```

and assign `mp3FileNames` to this variable by removing the `let` keyword

```
downloads = mp3FileNames
```

Comment: `The variable on the higher level is declared as optional constant. You can't change it!` is **not** true, the compiler is able to detect if the variable is initialized just once in the following control flows.. as an example you can take the code from my answer and use it as a "test" code

Comment: OK, I should rephrase, cause the claim is true, but in this case he is not making a change to it, rather initializing it later after it was declared, which is possible..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ It's nonsensical anyway. You will get a compiler error *in this case* because it's not initialized *exhaustive* (not in the `catch` scope)

Comment: that's why in my answer I included the initialization in `catch` branch too, so you don't get the error then.. we could argue about non-sensicallity of it, but there are cases in which you want a constant, not a variable, but there is a condition which needs more than a ternary operator (as this case is).. now since we do not know what he is going to do with the `downloads` variable I believe it is a valid assumption that he really wanted a `let` constant and not a variable..

Comment: I agree *there are cases in which you want a constant* but in most cases not an *optional* constant.

Comment: OK, I have to agree with this argument :D

Answer (score 0):

First declare global String var

```
var downloads: String?
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

Then use func to get all fileNames with mp3 extension

```
func fileNames() -> String {
    if let directoryContents = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: []) {
        let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
        let mp3FileNames = mp3Files.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
        return mp3FileNames.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
    return ""
}
```

And finally

```
downloads = fileNames()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you are looking for:

```
// not a string, but an array of strings
let downloads : [String]?

let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

do {
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    print(directoryContents)

    let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
    let mp3FileNames = mp3Files.map { $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }

    // do not use let, that will create a new variable, just the name of the constant is enough
    downloads = mp3FileNames

} catch {
    // you have to initialize the downloads constant in this control flow branch too, therefore here we assign nil to it
    downloads = nil

    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

// work with downloads
print(downloads)
```